# Firefox log in problem

Tags: firefox

I have recently converted an oldish computer from Window 7 to XUbuntu and have installed the latest Firefox as the search engine. However, when I log on to Firefox, the computer simultaneously logs on to Terminal Emulator. This does not prevent either program from working normally, so it is more of an irritation than a problem, but how can I resolve this?

Many thanks in anticipation of some help.

Comment: What do you mean by _log on to Firefox_?

Comment: I mean signing in by tapping on the firefox icon.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

MenuLibre is a handy editor for launcher icon.
It can edit almost all the menu icon detail by GUI.

`sudo apt install menulibre`

Then execute MenuLibre and find Firefox in the list.

[image: Menulibre1]

Set this command as I write and check `Option, Run in Terminal Off`.

Comment: My system tells me that I have the latest version of MenuLibre. How can I use this to prevent Terminal Emulator being launched at the same time as Firefox? Currently, if I delete Firefox, Terminal Emulator is deleted as well (and vice-vers!)

Comment: Did you execute MenuLibre and edit the item of Firefox, also look at `Options` > `Run in terminal` is off. Inside the icon, these things to do are described. You are going to change them by this application. You don't remove either Firefox or Terminal from system.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure that I understand what you are suggesting, but I'll give it a try and come back later if it doesn't work. I do appreciate your advice though.

Comment: Very sorry but I am totally baffled as to what I need to do to resolve this problem. If someone could set this out very simply for me, I would be really grateful.                                                      Many thanks

Comment: Well I've just had another try and bingo - I've done it - although if I had to go back and do it again I'd have no idea of how!!!!            But many thanks to those who have tried to help me - I do appreciate this.

Comment: I am happy that you managed what you wanted. If you think the answer is legitimate you can upvote. Downvote if it is another way round.